# How Angular JS Deep linking works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deep-linking

Using Angular 1.4

When I try to enter the following url in url bar,

```
https://application.com/movies/index.html?cd=1501739429812#/Movies/Action/2
```

the first request sent to server contains the url (Networks tab Chrome)

```
https://application.com/movies/index.html?cd=1501739429812
```

only, but still the application loads the page requested.

How is it passing `#/Movies/Action/2` to load the correct route.

First Request sent to server from browser :

```
Request URL: https://application.com/movies/index.html?cd=1501739429812
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
```

the hashbang content is not passed.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the answer in your AngularJS routes configuration. The hash contents are never passed to the server, and this is the reason why many developers face problems when they turn on HTML5 mode in AngularJS routing.

If you observe the response of the returned content, you will notice that it doesn't have the details of `/Movies/Action/2` either.

But it does have a script to bootstrap AngularJS, and its routes. So, once your page has been loaded in the browser, AngularJS and the routing mechanism pitch in. They observe your browser URL's hash content, and act accordingly (load `/Movies/Action/2` in your case).